# Не работает функция на JS

Tags: html, css

```js
    var leftdis;
    leftdis = document.getElementById('left_bar');

    function leftmn() {
      if (leftdis.style.display == 'none') {
        leftdis.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        leftdis.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
```

```css
#left_bar {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
#left_triger {
  height: 24px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="left_triger" onclick="leftmn()">Menu</a>
```

js:

```
var leftdis;
leftdis = document.getElementById('left_bar');
function leftmn(){
    if (leftdis.style.display == 'none'){
        leftdis.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        leftdis.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

css:

```
#left_bar{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
#left_triger{
    height: 24px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

Вопрос: Почему не хочет работать функция?
Фишка в том, что на другом проекте работает..

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что она не работает?

Comment: Страница не перезагружается при нажатии? Я обычно в <a href=""> пишу "#" или "javascript:", если нужно, чтобы ссылка не производила навигацию

Comment: return false; при вызове функции не забыли?

Comment: ну, началось гадание. Приму участие: `document.getElementById('left_bar');` - до того как загрузился элемент.

Comment: @Igor, не понял..можно подробней?

Comment: строка `leftdis = document.getElementById('left_bar');` выполняется сразу как распарсится. Если она в странице находится выше элемента с id 'left_bar', то этот элемент не будет найден и `leftdis` присвоится `null`.

Comment: @Igor, действительно. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не было блока `id="left_bar"`, после onclick не было `return false;` выполнялся поиск элемента до его инициализации.

```js
function leftmn() {
  var leftdis;
  leftdis = document.getElementById('left_bar');
  if (leftdis.style.display == 'none') {
    leftdis.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    leftdis.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#left_bar {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
#left_triger {
  height: 24px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="left_triger" onclick="leftmn();return false;">Menu</a>
<div id="left_bar" style="display:none">bar</a>
```